# Cauchy implies monotone + bounded

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

In my whole problem, I was stuck in one direction, which is to show (i) implies (ii).

> (i) Every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges to a limit in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> (ii) Every monotone and bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges to a limit in $\mathbb{R}$.

Explaining in english, my idea is:
Cauhcy is a bounded sequence. Given that (i) is true, i.e: this bounded cauchy sequence is convergent. Then, since not every bounded sequence is convergent, it requires some conditions so that it is convergent. One of a condition is "monotone". So, I try to use this to show (i) implies (ii). But my TA think "this is saying nothing".

If I would like to use some maths to explain, like $\epsilon$, a sequence $\{x_n\}$ etc.... How could I use it??

Comment: What you need to do is demonstrate that a monotone bounded sequence is Cauchy. By (i) it is then convergent which will prove (ii). Try doing that by the definition of a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: By the way, it looks like your title does not quite match the question : to prove that (i) implies (ii) you need to prove that every monotone bounded sequence is Cauchy, not the converse.

Comment: I will still read and see whether it helps me. Thank you @ArnaudD.